# Why use a path integral if we have a general solution to the Schrödinger equation?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, path-integral

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437825/), the general solution to the Schrödinger equation is given, and is also included [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/Scheq.html). In my QM class we talk a lot about this equation, but we haven't seen [path integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) yet, and I don't know if we will. I'm still curious about one thing, though.

I can't wrap my head around why we need a path integral for the wavefunction if we know how the solution to the time-dependent Schrödinger equation looks. What don't I get... why not use that all the time?

Comment: Actually, the path integral is kind of derived from the generic solution of the Schrödinger equation, so it contains no more or less than the Schrödinger equation. But the path integral turns out to refer directly to the classical action principle, which makes it pretty easy to generalize it to fields instead of particles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you reference only works if you already know what the energies are *and* the energy is the only quantum number needed to describe the Hilbert space. In general, we won't know ahead of time what the possible energies are, what states they correspond to if we do, or anything what other quantum numbers are attached to the states of our Hilbert space (for example, angular momentum).

These complications are multiplied when we do field theory because, essentially, there's even more freedom involved than in regular QM...the Hilbert spaces are bigger and more things can happen. Plus I'll note that the path integral gives a very nice perturbative approach to quantum mechanics. In regular QM this is sometimes called the WKB approximation. In field theory this is the machinery of Feynman diagrams.

Comment: Oh, ok, this makes sense. So usually we don't *really* know what the solution look like, not for an actual problem?

Comment: @rage_man That's correct. Finding the energy spectrum (allowed energy eigenvalues) is a major problem in physics generally. If you class has not yet gotten to perturbation theory: you'll note that the entire point is, really, to try and approximate the energies.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to have several ways to approach a problem, not least because it can give you new insights or allow you to solve other types of problems. Moreover, certainly imo, the path integral approach is conceptually much nicer and very logical. If you want a quick intro to path integral I suggest you read the first chapter of Zee’s QFT in a nutshell. It has a nice (made up) anecdote to explain why path integrals are so logical.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the reference! We use sections from Griffiths, so I'll be sure to check this one out.

Comment: It is a very easy and enjoyable read.